# Problems with my running a bat file in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I cant get the following bat file to run

```
cd/
FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('dir /S /b network_run.r') DO SET Prog="%F"
timout 30
echo %Prog%
```

It just crashes and its too quick to see the error

Any help would be great

Comment: are you trying to CD to the root dir? also, running from batch file requires to double up on predefined variables so `%` so make them `%%` but not for `%prog%` only `%%F`

Comment: Open a command prompt window and type the path/name of the batch file to execute it, so you can read any errors that appear; "it just crashes" is not a precise error description...

Comment: I think that is exactly what I needed - I didn't know about the %% convention. If you answer ill accept it

Comment: Rather than downvote - as I presume you already know the information - how about sharing a resource so I can learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `cd/` works, It is recommended to use the windows standard `\` so rather do `cd\`

When running from batch file, you need to double up on the `%` for predefined token variables, also, make sure you spell `timeout` correctly as `timout` command does not exist:

From batch file:

```
@echo off
cd\
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /S /b network_run.r') do set Prog="%%F"
timeout 30
echo %Prog%
```

if you were to find more than one result, you would need to preferbly set `delayedexpansion` do `set /?` from cmdline for more on that.